# How do I partition a graph in Python using Gurobi?

Tags: gurobi

I am working on a graph partitioning problem where I want to divide the following graph into two zones with the objective of cutting minimum number of lines.

[image]

Here is the math behind it:

[image]

Binary variables  which will take the value 1 when vertex  is included in subset , and the value 0 otherwise (i.e.,  is included in subset ).  Binary variables  model the case where edges are incident to different subsets, i.e.,  = 1 if the endpoints of edge {, } are across  and ,  = 0 otherwise.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

@Sagnik Please use this research: https://doi.org/10.1109/IPDPSW.2018.00053 by Kirmani and Madduri. To achieve the partition you need to compute the degree normalized matrix for the graph. The second eigenvector, also called the fielder vector will give the partition that you are looking for. May I ask you how big is your graph?